# UdpClient does not receive any messages

Tags: c#, networking, udp, broadcast

I want to display every UDP Broadcast Message my PC receives on a specific port.

I've wrote this simple .Net 7 Console app:

```
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

UdpClient udpClient = new(1900, AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
IPEndPoint? from = default;

while (true)
{
    var buffer = udpClient.Receive(ref from);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));
}
```

But I'll never receive any message. Running Wireshark reveals that there are many messages I should capture:

[image]

The local IP-Address of my PC is 192.168.178.119 and Subnet Mask is 255.255.255.0.
I've tried to run the application as administrator and even with disabled Firewall.

My goal in the end is to receive the device discovery requests from an Amazon Echo and respond to it.

Comment: The protocol is SSDP, not UDP.

Comment: The underlying transport protocol for SSDP is UDP as far as I know.

Comment: It is multicast so you need to join a multicast group.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.udpclient.joinmulticastgroup?view=net-7.0.  Multicast is a broadcast UDP that starts with 224 t0 239.  You can see in wireshark the ip = 239.255.255.250

Answer (score 0):

As correctly stated by @jdweng it's not a Broadcast I want to receive, but a multicast. Thanks!